# Fixed placed element within certain area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fixed, element

I have a page where I display a long list of results from a DB query.. and I also show a Google Map to the RIGHT of this long list.

Map is roughly 240px wide and maybe 600px long/height.

This MAP is inside a container DIV (#mapContainer).. that contains the map, and a dropdown box above the map canvas.

Currently, the mapContainer scrolls along with the page itself..  what I would like to do is have it be static/fixed element.  So it starts/displays/is placed where I have it currently on the page.... if I scroll the page.. the map should stay fixed.. until the end (bottom) of the results are scrolled to..

(I dont want the mapContainer to scroll and cover the footer element/div)

Following this tutorial:
http://www.webgeekly.com/tutorials/jquery/a-simple-guide-to-making-a-div-static-as-you-scroll-past-it/

It doesnt stay fixed..

```
 //sticky map placement
            $(function () { 
                var msie6 = $.browser == 'msie' && $.browser.version < 7;
                if (!msie6) {
                    console.log("NOT IE 6");
                    var top = $('#mapContainer').offset().top;

                    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
                        console.log("scrolling.......");
                        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
                        if (y >= top) { 
                            $('#mapContainer').addClass('fixed');
                            console.log("class added");
                        }else { 
                            $('#mapContainer').removeClass('fixed');
                            console.log("class removed");
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
```

The first console.log() outputs fine..  but nothign in the window.scroll() portion fires ever.

Rest of code used:

```
#mapContainer{
            display:table; 
            width:240px; 
            float:right;
            /* sticky map */
            position: absolute;         
            top: 458px;
            left: 50%;
            /* width: 100px; */
            margin-left: 339px;         
        }
        #<span class="skimlinks-unlinked">mapContainer.fixed</span> {
            position: fixed;
        }
```

On the tutorials page itself.. he has a toolbar on the left side..

that stops 'being fixed' when you scroll all the way to the top.. (it will start to move with the rest of the page scroll at a certain point).. and it doesnt go all the way down to cover the footer either.

I'm not clear why the jQuery portion isnt firing.. and I'm not clear what that last style is for?  (seems odd looking)

All this absolute, fixed, relative, to parent, to viewport..etc.. is confusing.

Any easy to read/follow/understand tutorials that will get me to where I want to be?  Or suggestions on what I am doing wrong with the correct approach?

Comment: Any chance you could put together a Fiddle for us to see what you're working with? Also, have you confirmed $('#mapContainer').offset().top; is finding the right element and not erroring? Oh, and in case you're interested in a plug-in: https://bigspotteddog.github.io/ScrollToFixed/

Comment: Sure.. I quickly mocked up a base layout.. here: http://jsfiddle.net/hkdvd88L/1/

Comment: Here is another version with the (failed) tutorials code (styles, jQuery..etc)

http://jsfiddle.net/pmurst8e/2/

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you want, but can't you just make the container fixed? http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/3juf6wnw/

Comment: That doesnt work. WHat if the box was longer (which it is.. it holds a google map inside of it. with is more longer than wider)..  you can never see it:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pmurst8e/3/

Comment: Looking at this page: http://www.webgeekly.com/tutorials/jquery/a-simple-guide-to-making-a-div-static-as-you-scroll-past-it/

(not the tutorials portion for now).. just his left side tool bar..

You notice, if you scroll.. the toolbox scroll with the page (for a little bit).. then stays FIXED,, if you scroll to a certain point..

I want this.. but ALSO for the bottom, so when while the map is 'fixed'.. and I scroll.. and get to the end/bottom of the results container.. it starts scrolling with the page again.. (not overlapping the footer or anything)

Does help make sense of what I am after?

Comment: I just had to do something similar with a site built using Bootstrap for a framework. The sidebar had sub-sections that could be expanded, forcing the sidebar to extend, even in a fixed mode. We had to allow that sidebar to be scrollable. In addition, when the window resized, the sidebar resized to the window height - 40px (top/bottom pad)

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your Fiddle and noticed a couple things:

1. Your "fixed" class was not represented in the CSS. When I looked into the CSS I saw a span element wrapping a ".fixed" reference with a position property set.
2. You are styling the mapContainer div using the ID. This is a very rigid selector as the order of CSS selectors goes. The hierarchy of CSS selectors is specifid and IDs will override types and classes. See: http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/structure.html
3. The when scrolling, I am seeing the console logging in my dev tools. Also, when inspecting the element, I am seeing it add and remove the class name.

Based on my observations, modifying the CSS selector for your container should do the trick. Adding the ID to the class will keep the CSS rule specific enough:

```
#mapContainer.fixed { position: fixed; }
```

Refer to this updated Fiddle for an example with these changes in place:
http://jsfiddle.net/pmurst8e/4/

**Update**: For demonstration purposes of what I was referring to with the resize I modified your example a bit. It isn't the prettiest, but it conveys the point: http://jsfiddle.net/pmurst8e/6/

**Update**: There are a couple issues with the latest Fiddle (v12):

1. The sidebar will always go fixed the moment you scroll because "top" is never calculated. It's being set to zero, and the offset calculation is commented out.
2. Absolute positioning is relative to the closest positioned parent. If no parent is positioned, it's relative to the window. To constrain an absolute positioned element, set the constraining parent to "position:relative;".
3. Instead of using a percentage and left position rule, consider positioning the sidebar to the right, relative to the "contentContainer", by a set number of pixels.
4. When the fixed position takes effect, we also need to set the sidebar fixed left position. Otherwise, it will use the positioning in the CSS. In contrast to absolute positioning, Fixed positioning is relative to the window, meaning an absolute element "right: 10px" will be 10px from the right of the positioned parent, but will appear 10px from the right of the window when fixed.
5. You don't need a float when you have absolute positioning. Absolute position removes an element from the normal flow of the document, and because of this float does not apply.

I updated the Fiddle to show how to make these adjustments. I cleaned out the float and margin from the mapContainer and left the absolute positioning. With that I set the contentContainer to relative to constrain mapContainer to it. You will also see, on the script side, I added a line to set the offset of mapContainer. Without this, when it becomes fixed it will be 10px off the right border of the window.

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pmurst8e/14/

Also, you want to leave your top offset line in tact. Without that, it goes fixed the moment the scroll moves and never goes back. When that becomes the case, you're better off just setting fixed permanently.

```
var top = $('#mapContainer').offset().top;    // you want this
```

Regarding the bottom boundary, you can do a couple things:

1. Resize the sidebar so that it shrinks to the window size. This is demoed in my example from my first post in this and the downside is it forces the sidebar to become a scrollable div so the child content is all visible.
2. Use a check for the bottom so that when you hit the limit, the container goes back to an absolute position, but one set at the bottom: 0 of the parent.

Something like:

```
var limit = $('footer').offset().top;
var $mc = $('#mapContainer');
var pos = $mc.offset().top + $mc.outerHeight();

if (pos >= limit) {
    $mc.removeClass('fixed')
       .addClass('bottom-set').css('left',''); // define this in CSS for bottom absoluteness
}

#mapContainer.bottomFixed {
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;
}
```

And to be fully honest, you might save yourself some time working this all out if you take a look at the ScrollToFixed plug-in (https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed). I seem to be mentioning it quite a bit lately, but this issue seems to be a popular one right now.

Incidentally, go to your OP and click the Edit button. Shrink the height of your browser and scroll down. You should see SO has a fixed sidebar that passed the footer. ;)

Comment: "Your "fixed" class was not represented in the CSS. When I looked into the CSS I saw a span element wrapping a ".fixed" reference with a position property set."
That is how it is in the tutorial link I posted above.. and even reference the same thing.  (no sure why it was like that)

Was if the forced scroll bar button supposed to do?  (Doesnt seem to do anything for me [Firefox])..

EDIT: I see the scrollbar now.. but that is the section that is supposed to stay fixed.. while the rest of the page scrolls..   (the link(s) above demostrate what I want (sorta) but tutorial is odd/not working.

Comment: this seems to almost 90% behave like I want it too:

http://jsfiddle.net/pmurst8e/12/

Its just when I move the 'frames' around in the fiddle screen going left/right..  I see it does NOT stay within its parent container...?  :(  

How can I fix this?

Notice how the whole 'page' scrolls.. but the 'map column' on the right stays fixed..  but does -not- overlap the footer when you scroll down far enough.  I just need it to not overlap the outside container(s)... when the width is changed.  (make sense?) :)

Comment: There are a couple issues in the latest fiddle posted. I will update my answer highlighting and addressing them. Also, the scroll thing I posted in V6 of the Fiddle was to show how you could have the sidebar resize with the window. When it's fixed, and someone shrinks the browser, anything below the fold is lost.

Comment: Thanks..  (I thought this question was abandoned)..

I have been all over the map with this one.. and cant see to get it to work as it does in the tutorial: http://www.webgeekly.com/tutorials/jquery/a-simple-guide-to-making-a-div-static-as-you-scroll-past-it/ 

Here is my real project for you to check out..easier then working in fiddle for now:
http://www.aacpdm.org/providers/index_gd.php?ZipCode=53154&Distance=200&Search=Search&page=11

I can not get the $(window).scroll() to fire in my jQuery function??  (but it does in Fiddle)...??

Comment: Also regarding your example #6.. just so I'm clear.. there would be NO scrollbars on anything.. except the browser window.  The whole blue 'box' needs to scroll with the page until the "results on the left" get to a certain point (at the top),,then the blue box is fixed.. while the rest of the page scrolls..   when you scroll far enough to the bottom.  it would 'stop' before scrolling outside the parent borders/boundaries...and not overlap the footer/content..  (It should really be JUST like the tutorial linked to).. but for whatever reason I cant get the $(window).scroll() to fire...

Comment: I made a new question about the $(window).scroll() stuff.. (thinking this thread was dead)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016656/window-scroll-function-doesnt-fire

Comment: On your page, the window is not what is scrolling. I think the Body is scrolling because of the height and overflow. If you remove the height: 100% from the body I think you will see the scroll event triggering. Your script is correct. It's just not the correct object scrolling. :)

Comment: Please make that an answer (here or the other post).. the body 100% garbage was for sure the cuplrit (I didnt originally make those styles.. so I wasnt aware it was even there!   Good call/catch on that stopping the scrolling from happening!!!!!  +1

Comment: Follow up question.. is there anything that can be done to make it 'act' absolute  (when in fixed mode).. so that the element does NOT go beyond the boundaries/borders of the parent container(s)?  Possibly through the JS function that sets the .fixed class.. to update a 'current' left value? or something?

Like whenever the JS function to add the class fires.. it always has the mapContainer to the utmost RIGHT.. with a 10px margin on the right?  (like always have it justified/floated right with a 10px margin on the right side?)

Comment: Not when it's fixed. The only time a fixed element gets bounded by a different container is when a transform occurs on a parent, and then a fixed element behaves like an absolute, but that would be in direct contrast to how you want it to behave. Shoot me an email and ask the question (see my profile) and maybe there is something else that can be done.

Comment: PS. I just dealt with a complex application with a very detailed and expansive sidebar that did something similar so I might be able to help.

Comment: I'd be interested to see it.  I feel like I am just making things worse here.. trying to fix little 'scenarios'..   Currently.. if screen is maximized..  the scroll seems to work fine...

If however I adjust the browser size to be a bit smaller.. the mapContainer scrolls over and overlaps the footer section..  (put in a bottom boundary check??)

http://www.aacpdm.org/providers/index_gd.php?ZipCode=53154&Distance=200&Search=Search&page=11

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72879/discussion-between-daved-and-whispers).