# $(window).scroll function doesnt fire

Tags: jquery, scroll, window, positioning

I am trying to implement this tutorial technique into my current project:
http://www.webgeekly.com/tutorials/jquery/a-simple-guide-to-making-a-div-static-as-you-scroll-past-it/

(specifically the relative/fix social media tool bar on the left side)

- doesnt start to be 'fixed' until a certain scroll value.
- stops being 'fixed' before the footer (as to not overlap it)

I have been following along, but the $(window).scroll() function never fires for me.. (only in a fiddle example/test)..  the other console.log() inside the $(document).ready() fire..but noting inside the $(window).scroll() function?

```
//sticky map placement
        $(function(){           
            var msie6 = $.browser == 'msie' && $.browser.version < 7;
            if (!msie6) {
                console.log("NOT IE 6");
                console.log($(window).scrollTop());
                var top = $('#mapContainer').offset().top;
                console.log("TOP: "+top);
                var bottom = $('#directory').height() + $('#directory').offset().top;;
                console.log("BOTTOM: "+bottom);
                //var top = 458;                
                $(window).scroll(function (event) {
                    console.log("scrolling.......");
                    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
                    if (y >= top) { 
                        $('#mapContainer').addClass('fixed');
                        console.log("class added");
                    }else { 
                        $('#mapContainer').removeClass('fixed');
                        console.log("class removed");
                    }
                });         
            }
        });
```

Relevant styles:  (been changed many times in an attempt to get things working)

(mapContainer parent)

```
#col-2 {            
            float:right;        
            width:935px!important;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;   
            position: relative; 
            height:auto;
        }


#mapContainer{
            display:table; 
            width:240px;            
            /* sticky map (fixed position after certain amount of scroll) */

            /*float:right;*/

            position: absolute;         
            top: 140px;
            left: 685px;
            margin-left: 10px;                      
        }   

        .fixed{
            position: fixed;
        }
```

Mottie suggest code updates (remove the use of .browser).. commented it out.. still not firing.. :(

```
//sticky map placement
        $(function(){           
            //var msie6 = $.browser == 'msie' && $.browser.version < 7;
            //if (!msie6) {
                console.log("NOT IE 6");
                console.log($(window).scrollTop());
                var top = $('#mapContainer').offset().top;
                console.log("TOP: "+top);
                var bottom = $('#directory').height() + $('#directory').offset().top;;
                console.log("BOTTOM: "+bottom);
                //var top = 458;                
                $(window).scroll(function (event) {
                    console.log("scrolling.......");
                    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
                    if (y >= top) { 
                        $('#mapContainer').addClass('fixed');
                        console.log("class added");
                    }else { 
                        $('#mapContainer').removeClass('fixed');
                        console.log("class removed");
                    }
                });         
            //}
        });
```

The console.log()'s fire just fine.. but no scrolling functions..

For @Daved -

Here is my latest/current function:  but when you scroll back UP it jumps out of place again:

```
//sticky map placement
        $(function(){           
            //var msie6 = $.browser == 'msie' && $.browser.version < 7;
            //if (!msie6) {
                console.log("NOT IE 6");
                console.log($(window).scrollTop());
                var top = $('#mapContainer').offset().top;
                console.log("TOP: "+top);
                var bottom = $('#directory').height() + $('#directory').offset().top;;
                console.log("BOTTOM: "+bottom);
                var $mc = $('#mapContainer');

                var containerWidth = $('#col-2').position().left + $('#col-2').width();
                var placementPoint = containerWidth - $('#mapContainer').width();
                //var top = 458;                
                $(window).scroll(function (event) {
                    console.log("scrolling.......");
                    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
                    if (y >= top) {                     
                        $('#mapContainer').offset({left:placementPoint});                                           
                        $('#mapContainer').addClass('fixed');
                        console.log("class added");
                    }else {                         
                        $('#mapContainer').removeClass('fixed');
                        //$('#mapContainer').offset({top:140, left:685});   
                        console.log("class removed");
                    }
                });         
            //}
        });
```

Comment: if you put a breakpoint when you add the scroll event listener is it stopping? The code you posted looks fine.

Comment: Don't use `$.browser` - it has been [removed from jQuery v1.9+](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

Comment: The issue is that your window is not what's scrolling :) I posted more info to the original thread you had.

Comment: @ Mottie-  thanks.

I have updated the function: (above in original post)


@Daved what do you mean?  I am not scrolling the browser window using the browser scrollbar?

Comment: The scrollbar is on the body, not on the window. Basically, an overflow is causing the scrollbar to appear but it's on an element not on the window.

Comment: @Daved you are correct.. removing that crappy body {height:100%} worked!  I need to tweak the 'fixed' style so it doesnt jump to an odd left/right position now!  Thanks!   I spent way too much time tracking this down!   I owe you a drink sir!  lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comment to answer to help identify what the culprit was.

The scrollbar is on the body, not on the window. Basically, an overflow is causing the scrollbar to appear but it's on an element not on the window.

Comment: hmm.. I need a LITTLE bit more help here..

I'm close.

http://www.aacpdm.org/providers/index_gd.php?ZipCode=53154&Distance=200&Search=Search&page=11

Works fine on initial load..scroll down.. works fine.. (I adjusted the positioning to be same as when it initially loads)..  but when I scroll up and the class is removed..(no longer fixed..the position gets wonky again).. do I need to re-set tings to be absolute? and new position values?

Original post updated for current function ^^